# how to locate this syntax error : SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue at

Tags: javascript, vuex, vuejs3

When trying to build my vu3js SPA I get the following error

> vite v2.9.12 building for production... ✓ 75 modules transformed.
>
> [rollup-plugin-dynamic-import-variables] Assigning to rvalue (1907:44)
>
> file:
> /ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/src/components/RecipeEditor.vue:1907:44
>
> error during build:

SyntaxError: Assigning to rvalue (1907:44)

> ```
> at Parser.pp$4.raise (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19738:13)
> at Parser.pp$7.toAssignable (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18231:12)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeAssign (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18754:21)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19209:28)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseExprAtom (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:19072:41)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseExprSubscripts (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18905:19)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeUnary (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18871:17)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseExprOps (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18798:19)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeConditional (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18781:19)
> at Parser.pp$5.parseMaybeAssign (/ORIGINAL-P1/LARAVEL-BREW/BrewersCompanion/vue/node_modules/rollup/dist/shared/rollup.js:18748:19)
> ```

I cannot see anything like assigning to right hand value around line 1907

Here is a chunk of code starting at line 1905

```
//Gravity (line 1905)
let fixed_og = ref();

let showConfirmGravity = ref(false);
function adaptFermentablesToNewGravity() {
    let equipment = store.getters["equipment/getEquipmentById"](
        recipe_model.equipment
    );
    let old_extract_added_to_boil = extract_added_to_boil.value;
    let old_extract_from_mash = extract_from_mash.value;
    let P = SGToPlato(recipe_model.original_gravity);
  
    if (P < 1) {
        P = 1;
    }
    //original gravity is for postboil volume
    let new_extract_mass = extract_mass_from_platos_and_volume(
        P,
        postboil_volume_reverse_cold.value
    );
    //FOR MASH
    let new_extract_from_mash =
        (new_extract_mass * old_extract_from_mash) /
        (old_extract_added_to_boil + old_extract_from_mash);

    recipe_model.fermentables.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.use === "mash") {
            element.quantity =
                1 *
                (element.quantity / old_extract_from_mash) *
                new_extract_from_mash;
        }
    });

    //FOR BOIL
    let new_extract_added_at_boil =
        (new_extract_mass * old_extract_added_to_boil) /
        (old_extract_added_to_boil + old_extract_from_mash);

    recipe_model.fermentables.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.use === "boil" || element.use === "steep") {
            element.quantity =
                1 *
                (element.quantity / old_extract_added_to_boil) *
                new_extract_added_at_boil;
        }
    });
}
```

Could somebody help me finding where the problem is located ?

**EDIT AFTER COMMENTS EXCHANGED**

I fixed the trouble but I do not understand what exactly it was.

I commented my script by very little chunks until the build command returns no error at all.

Then I reintroduced each chunk that didn't trigger an error.  At last there were only to chunks left. They were similar and like this

```
const after_sparge_and_lauter_volume_hot_display = computed(() => {
    return adapt_volume_to_unit(after_sparge_and_lauter_volume_hot.value);
});
```

Their conterpart in the template was like this

```
<div
   class="flex flex-row w-full justify-start align-middle"
>
   <label class="w-80">
       {{i18n.$t("After Sparge Boil Volume (hot)")}}
   </label>
   <div class="flex flex-row">
       <input
          type="number"
          v-model="after_sparge_and_lauter_volume_hot_display"
          class="w-20 h-5 ml-2 mr-4 text-sx bg-cyan-100"
          disabled="true"
        />
          {{ volume_initial_selection }}
    </div>
   </div>
```

As I was already using this kind of code pattern very frequently without any problem, I could not see what was wrong.

Thus I deleted the template chunk and  rewrite it apparently ( only apparently) exactly the same.

This fixed the problem.

As for the line number (1907) I cannot undertand .

Comment: you must have the wrong file ... if what you posted starts at line 1905, then 1907 is an empty line

Comment: No I don't. The file is RecipeEditor.vue as mentionned in the error message and yes line 1907 is empty. Weird! Isn't it?

Comment: do you have code first or template first in your .vue file? perhaps the line number is calculated incorrectly

Comment: The template is first. I fixed the problem but without understanding very well. Please, read the edit I added to the initial post for details.